# Displaying multiple resources under one

Tags: react-admin

I would like to know whether it's possible to have two resources under one.
Example:
<Resource name="notifications" options={{ label: "Push Notifications"}} icon={NotificationsActiveIcon} list={NotificationsList} create={NotificationsCreate} edit={NotificationsEdit} />

Now I would like to have something like Resource name="notificationAudience but to access that data in the notifications resource. So pretty much create data in one Create for two resources. Is something like this possible in React Admin? If so please do share an accurate/detailed explanation on how something like this would be possible. So far I couldn't find what is satisfying in React Admin documentation

Thank a lot!

Comment: This sounds possible. Can you tell us which component are you passing to the `<Resource name="notificationAudience" />` list prop? Did you want to re-use the same NotificationsList component?